# css - position div's on oppersite sides of container

Tags: css

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dxzkov?file=App.tsx,style.css)

Super simple but I'm stuck

I have a div container containing 6 divs

I need the position the red div on the right of the container but still keep the layout of the divs.

If I try `position: absolute; right: 0;` or `float: right;`

all the div's collapse on top of each other.

How can I position the even divs on the right and keep the structure

```
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
  /* position: absolute;
  right: 0; */
  /* float: right; */
}

.block {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox and the `align-self` property, you can achieve this goal. Here's [a fork of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9s7rap?file=App.tsx,style.css) with the fix.

I added `display: flex` to the parent, `flex-direction: column` to keep your design, and simply `align-self: flex-end` on one of the child that has to be on the right.

Hope it help, good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
.block.two {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

https://react-ts-h2pzuh.stackblitz.io/